# Task nativeTest Failed

Tags: java, graalvm

I was trying to run tests on spring java project using GraalVM. Upon which stumbled to this error.
according to the documentation the test first runs using the JVM and then compiles the test and then runs with GraalVM.

every time i try to run `gradle nativeTest` the follwing error occurs.
each class will have these set of errors

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groupController': Unexpected AOP exception

org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CGLIB runtime enhancement not supported on native image. Make sure to include a pre-generated class on the classpath instead: com.kv.authservice.group.GroupController$$SpringCGLIB$$87
```

I tried different configurations and cannot find a solution.

upon which i added to Runtimehints.

```
hints.proxies().registerJdkProxy(TransactionAutoConfiguration.EnableTransactionManagementConfiguration.CglibAutoProxyConfiguration.class);
```

doing this will move the `gradle nativeTest` further more and also produce this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load AOT ApplicationContextInitializer class for test class [com.kv.authservice.group.CreateGroupTest]. This can occur if AOT processing has not taken place for the test suite. It can also occur if AOT processing failed for the test class, in which case you can consult the logs generated during AOT processing.
```

this also bring another issue as once this hints is added then we cannot build native image also.

Comment: I ran some sample project in my local in linux tests are working, can you share a reproducer ?

Comment: @ozkanpakdil I couldn't isolate exactly which package caused the error it may be Lombok or spring might be using the CGLIB package as its dependency.
I guess if you include such libraries and use springboot Starter test for testing, you could reproduce the error